# Failed Login on Registered Server When Opening Connection

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssms

I have a number of servers registered in the Registered Servers pane in SQL Server Management Studio.

When I right click a server group and select "New Query", a window opens in which I can execute a command against all the servers in that group.

Every time I do this, one of the servers (the same one each time) registers a failed login (We have Email alerts set up for failed logins) and gives the following error description

> DESCRIPTION:  Login failed for user 'MyUser'. Reason: Failed to open
>   the explicitly specified database '<multiple>'. [CLIENT:
>   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]

however, I can then run a query in the window and it executes against all servers including the one throwing the login error.

I thought there was maybe a configuration option on this server that was different to all the others but having compared `sys.configurations` between the servers I can see the only config that is out is the max server memory (MB) and affinity mask.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: "Failed to open the explicitly specified database" makes me think that something is, well, specifying the database. In the Registered Servers entry for the problematic server, check Properties, Connection Properties, "Connect to database". Perhaps you have an invalid or offline database specified in there. (Although that doesn't match with your statement about being able to run the query successfully.)

Comment: This looks very similar to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138011/sql-server-management-studio-creates-18456-login-error-using-registered-server-g?rq=1 and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23042/login-failure-error-log-when-querying-central-management-server-group?rq=1 and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51330/multi-server-query-generating-login-failures?rq=1. None of those have helpful answers, but reading through the comments might give you something to try.